# How to determine if a Perl module is cross-platform?

Tags: perl

For example, I want to compress log files a script generates. I'm using version 5.8.8 so there isn't anything built into the core to do it. The script is cross-platform, Linux, Solaris, AIX, HPUX, and Windows.

Right now I'm thinking of using `IO::Compress::Gzip`. Are there any known bugs with that module? Will it work across all platforms?

To generalize a little more, how can I find out if a certain module has any known bugs, and what platforms that module will run on?

Comment: IO::Compress::Gzip is a core module so _should_ work on every platform Perl supports.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CPAN offers an array of tools you can use to determine the usefulness of a module before installing it. Unfortunately, IO::Compress::Gzip is a suboptimal example of how this can go.

When you visit the [metacpan page of a module](https://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aCompress%3a%3aGzip), there is a list of tools in the left column. The interesting points are

- *Test Results:* This takes you to a page where the results of the test suite on different OSes and different perl versions are shown. Unfortunately, this service doesn't respond to my requests at the time of writing.
- [*Bugs:*](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=IO-Compress) This is a link to the bugtracker for this module. You can browse the list of open bugs to find possible dealbrakers. And if you find an issue, you can report it here.
- *Reviews:* Some modules have short reviews and ratings by the Perl community. The module you mentioned doesn't have any ratings yet, so as an example, here are the [ratings for List::MoreUtils](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/List-MoreUtils).
- [*Dependencies*](http://deps.cpantesters.org/?module=IO%3A%3ACompress%3A%3AGzip&perl=5.8.8&os=any+OS) are listed on the right column. If you click the “dependencies” link, you can get a summary of test results for the required non-core modules for a given perl version. Unfortunately, there don't seem to be any results available currently.

Many modules also have a “bugs and limitations” section in the documentation.

*Note:* according to the `corelist` program, `IO::Compress::Gzip` is a core module since perl5, v9.4. This doesn't mean much: Core modules are in Core because they are needed to install other modules (or because they have historical significance … CGI, *cough*). However, this is an indication that it is reasonably stable and thoroughly cross-platform.